# Tool to check illegal instruction in an executable in Linux

Tags: gcc, g++, elf, illegal-instruction

I have an application written in C/C++ and compiled with gcc/g++ with option -march=... in order to run on specific machine hardware.
After compiling, i copy that executable to the destination machine.
However, to make sure that it will run fine on that hardware, i wanna ask if there is any tool or way to examine that executable to see if it’s runnable (not contain any illegal instruction) without running the executable?

Comment: Searching for a tool is offtopic for stackoverflow. As for `is there any way..` I think: 1. from `/proc/cpuinfo` you can know which instructions sets are supported. 2. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings) has a mapping (set name) -> (instructions) and 3. `objdump` can list assembly instructions in an executable. Those tools could be just enough to detect.